# Use generic class as generic type in Java

Tags: java, generics

When I try to do this:

```
public <T> List<T> get(String key, Class<T> classType) {
        List<classType> list = new ArrayList<classType>();
    }
```

Gives me unknown class error

Comment: `T` is your generic type, `classType` is just a parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need the `classType` parameter to create a `List`. Since your method is generic and has a generic parameter `T`, `T` is the type you should use!

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Do you mean if I do this:
List<MyObject> list = get();
without any params it will wok just fine

Comment: @AhmedElmokadim Yes, because the type of `T` can be inferred. But don't forget the `key` parameter though!

Comment: Look when I try to do it with Gson lib like this:

public <T> List<T> get(String key) {
      if (preferences.contains(key)) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(get(key, ""), type);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }

Exception happend:
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.mokadim.project.MyObject

Comment: @AhmedElmokadim Right, so you are working with GSON. You need to convert the value returned by `gson.fromJson(get(key, ""), type)` to `MyObject`. I don't think it has anything to do with this question. I suggest you ask a new question about this exception if you are stuck.